# Django displaying all users

Tags: python, html, django

I want to display all the  users, in my template but I cannot. I think there is a mistake in my codes but I cannot find it. Here is codes.

**views.py**

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsersView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = UserList.objects.all()
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
class UserList(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="The first name of the user.")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="The last name of the user.")
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text="The email and username of the user. Required."
    )
```

**users.html**

```
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Users:</h1>

    <ul>

        {% for users in object_list %}
            <li class="user">{{ user }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is the page that I get:

Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: What exacty is the page you get?

Comment: I find it rather strange that you name the model `UserList`. Normally Django models are named in a *singular* way, here you "hint" that an object is in fact a *list* of `User`s.

Comment: If you want the users registered in the Django system, it is probably the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model you are after, the default model used for authentication.

Comment: There is my page:  https://prnt.sc/ktz1cf

Answer (score 2):

Your code includes the following:

```
    {% for users in object_list %}
        <li class="user">{{ user }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

The trouble with this is that the `user` template variable is not defined. Change `users` to `user` in the loop header and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django.contrib.auth.models.User` on your view with `request.user.get_username()` with this you use a standard user with Django. If go go admin URL you see user default.

For call in template :

`{{ user.get_username }}`